# PostgreSQL- Round REAL data type (yes, I know numeric exist)

Tags: sql, postgresql, rounding, real-datatype

I know REAL data type is not accurate and normally for currency I should use **numeric** data type.
But, I'm asked to do some stuff and one of the conditions is that the data type is real.
When I try to do `round((....),2)` for example, I get that round function does not exist for this data type.
My question is, without converting, is there any function that can return a REAL value rounded to 0?

Many thanks!1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-math.html) it's no way to round without any type cast. It's only two kinds of function exists:

**round(dp or numeric)** - round to nearest integer

**round(v numeric, s int)** - round to s decimal places

Real = double precision. So you need to use convert anyway if you want to get some decimal places:

```
select round('123.456789'::real::numeric,2)
```

**upd.** Keep care about rounding+cast at big real numbers:

```
select round('12122156.567'::real::numeric, 2); --< rounding up to 6 digits, result = 12122200
select round('12122156.567'::real::DOUBLE PRECISION::numeric,2); --<< rounding result = 12122157
```

Or you can use round without decimal places:

```
select round('123.456789'::real)
```

Answer (score 0):

round a numeric value to 0 after the dot?

```
ROUND(numeric_value, 0)
```

Comment: maybe you can give a specific example of what are you trying to do

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, converting to ::numeric is the only way around